# CVOpenGLESTextureCache missing in monotouch sample GLCameraRippleSample

Tags: xamarin.ios

i have download the monotuch sample GLCameraRipple

But when i try to compile it, an error appears in CVOpenGLESTextureCache and GLKViewDrawEventArgs:

the type or namespace CVOpenGLESTextureCache could not be found.

GLCameraRipperViewController.Update() is marked as an override but not suitable method found to override.

As the sample is not packed into the download file on github, i had to copy & paste all the code!!! May be i've done something wrong, but everything seems ok ( but it doesn't!!)

Thanks everybody!!

Answer (score 1):

This code is only available in the upcoming MonoTouch 5.4, you can get a preview from the Alpha channel in MonoDevelop.